# Why does the input text fields not appear

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently debugging a bigger system, but have tried to take out the parts I think that are posing the problems.

I can't quite see why the input text fields aren't appended to the HTML in [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qygB2/104/).

The JS code:

```
 for (var counter = 0; counter < 20; counter++) {

    var anbox = $(document.createElement('input')).attr({
        type: 'text',
        class: 'anBox',
        size: '1',
        maxlength: '1'
    });
    anbox.appendTo('#answerLine_' + i);};
```

Comment: Sure its just a minor brain fart.

Comment: your HTML is a disaster O_o

Comment: Yeah I know its not good.. Not my work.. :p

Comment: Try like this :           <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            for (var counter = 1; counter < 5; counter++) {
                var anbox = $(document.createElement('input')).attr({
                    type: 'text',
                    class: 'anBox',
                    size: '1',
                    maxlength: '1',
                    id: 'a' + counter
                });                
                anbox.appendTo('#answerLine_1');
            };
        });
    </script>

Answer (score 6):

Yeah, it is minor. There is no `i` variable defined, it should be `counter` instead:

```
anbox.appendTo('#answerLine_' + counter);
```

In order to search for such problems I suggest you to use debugging tools like Chorme Developer Console or Firebug.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/qygB2/106/

Comment: Ahh I was to fast.. ty!

Answer (score 0):

wheres **i** coming from in the following line:

```
anbox.appendTo('#answerLine_' + i);};
```

I think you have to change it to:

```
anbox.appendTo('#answerLine_' + counter);};
```

I changed; and it worked; see:

http://jsfiddle.net/qygB2/105/

Answer (score 0):

```
anbox.appendTo('#answerLine_' + i)
```

change  `i` to `counter`

```
anbox.appendTo('#answerLine_' + counter)
```